# save the state of the whole page in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I know that if i am on a page and i **navigate** to another page, the **state** of the earlier page will be preserved and reloaded as it was if i press the back button. However my problem is that i want to navigate from page **1** to **2** then **3** and back to **1**, hence i want to save the state of page **1** to reload it when i come back from page **3**.

So is there an easy and predefined way to do this or should i save all the variables and reload them manually on **NavigatedTo**???

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isnt an easy way, save the values and manually load them back in.

Comment: Thanks, however i found a better way by simply removing the previous entry in navigation stack when navigated to page 3 then when i need to go back to page 1 i use NavigationService.GoBack() and this should do the trick :D